# Using ifelse on two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column in my data frame using an `ifelse` condition like this:

Let's assume two data frames A and B, both having date and time columns.

If date in A matches a date in B and the date in A's time equals matching date in B's time or matching date in B's time is lower than next row's time in A, Then TRUE else FALSE.

I hope this is clear enough.. So far I have tried something like this

```
A %>% mutate(DFT = ifelse(Dayt == B$date & Tyme == B$time | 
                          Tyme > Time[which(Dayt == B$date & Tyme ==B$time) +1], 
    B[which(which(Dayt == B$date & Tyme ==B$time) +1])], NA))
```

This code may not work but I hope it gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sample input and expected output please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
A = data.frame(
  date=seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/1/10"), "days"))
B = data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2017/1/2"), as.Date("2017/1/9"), "days"))
A$time <- sample(1:3,length(A$date),TRUE)
B$time <- sample(1:3,length(B$date),TRUE)

 A   
      date time
 1: 2017-01-01    1
 2: 2017-01-02    2
 3: 2017-01-03    2
 4: 2017-01-04    3
 5: 2017-01-05    1
 6: 2017-01-06    3
 7: 2017-01-07    3
 8: 2017-01-08    2
 9: 2017-01-09    2
10: 2017-01-10    1

B
         date time
1: 2017-01-02    1
2: 2017-01-03    1
3: 2017-01-04    3
4: 2017-01-05    2
5: 2017-01-06    3
6: 2017-01-07    2
7: 2017-01-08    3
8: 2017-01-09    3
```

#### solution

Here a solution , First I merge by date then I filter using the time condition.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
setDT(B)

merge(A,B,by="date")[time.x==time.y | time.y==c(tail(time.x,-1),NA)]

        date time.x time.y
1: 2017-01-04      3      3
2: 2017-01-06      3      3
3: 2017-01-07      3      2
```

Comment: my data has duplicate dates. They are not unique entries so I will not be able to merge them by date.

Comment: @Kay Maybe if you provide a reproducible example we can help you...

Comment: Why did you convert to data table before merging A and B?

Comment: @Kay I am using data.table for more sugar syntax and performance. You can use data.frame but the code will be slightly different.